# How good are Harvard undergrads?

Tags: computer-science, undergraduate

I Studied **Computer Science Engineering** in India from an **average private institute**.

I wanted to and I still do want to become a great programmer. I have seen "The Social Network"(facebook) built and come to life right in front of my eyes. He was in his sophomore when he dropped out of college.

I don't know what they teach in Harvard in the very first year but over in India they teach C, C++ in the first two semesters . The curriculum revolved around learning basic syntax, functions, operators, pointers and ends up on files. C++ syllabus has somewhat of object oriented language pedagogy (few extra terms - inheritance, polymorphism etc.) . The problems which we were solving were those of .. writing area of triangle, towers of hanoi. Following these two semesters we studied data structures.

I don't see how a person can go on from his sophomore into building such a vast social network. I understand, he was a Harvard student, that must have meant something.

**But exactly how much ahead are they, compared to an "average Indian"?**

**Is it something to do with the course over there? or the problems they practice or the environment or the individual's efforts ?**

**And how much time is it going to take for an "Average Indian" to reach that level?**

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no single "correct" answer to your question.

Comment: Keep in mind that Zuckerberg was not an "average" Harvard student -
 most do not go on to be self-made billionaires. Beyond that, he didn't even complete half of his cirriculum at Harvard, so why do you think the Harvard education was the seed of his success?

Comment: I don't know about Harvard in particular but you have to keep in mind that not everyone from Harvard was so successful, and that not everyone who is successful has been in Harvard. If you are good you will success, and it will be minutely related to the "prestige" of your university

Comment: If you're interested in seeing the content of Harvard's introductory CS50 course, the whole thing is online here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/

Comment: You seem to be making the assumption that Zuckerberg founded Facebook using only knowledge/skills gained from his Harvard studies.

Comment: From the [list of social networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_networking_websites), one can see that at the moment when facebook appeared, there were also many additional social networks already created. From there to the domination of facebook over such a vast market is high gap, with possible political interference(and not presented in the movie). Learning a programming language professionally can be made only by working on real life projects, besides school projects which are very simple by comparison.